Label disappearing after reload
I have a frustrating bug where, when I select a value to filter something in my mat-table, the table is updated correctly, but when i reload a page, the set value goes back to default (which is ok) but the label that i set to be shown on default disappears until i click on the select again. Pictures are provided as attachments.
The code:
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{ "ticketScope.projectsLabel" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="selectedProjectId">
      <mat-option [value]="0">{{ "userInbox.all" | translate }}</mat-option>
      @for (project of projectList; track project) {
      <mat-option [value]="project.id?.toString()">
        {{ project.name }} | {{ project.fullName }}
      </mat-option>
      }
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

Scope after:

Scope before:


could you replicate the issue on angular material stackblitz examples and share back

i think you just need to initialize value of selectedProjectId
ngOnInit(): void { selectedProjectId = 0  }

